# Range and kernel of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $f: G \rightarrow H$ be a homomorphism. If the range of $f$ has $n$ elements, then $x^n \in$ ker $f$ for every $x \in G$.

---

I can kind of understand why this is true. The ker of $f$ is $\{x \in G$ | $f(x)=e_H \}$, where $e_H$ is the identity of $H$.

I need to show $f(x^n)=e_H$.  Since there is a homomorphism, $f(x^n)=f(x)^n$. Now I'm not sure how to connect this to the range of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)$ is an element of the range of $f$. Verify that the range of $f$ is a group. By lagrange's theorem $|f(x)|$ divides $n$. Hence, $f(x^n)=f(x)^n=e_H$. Thus, $x^n\in Ker f$